# How to make SVG Elements wrapped in Angular Component which is a Shadow DOM focusable by tabbing

Tags: angular, forms, svg, tabbing, focusable

I am trying to make use of the default behaviour when a user presses Tab to iterate over input elements.

I want to make SVG elements focusable by key stroke.
The SVG is wrapped inside a component.

```
<parent-component>
  <input>
  <child-component></child-component>
  <input>
</parent-component>
```

child-component.html

```
<svg>
  <g (click)='doSomething' tabindex='0' focusable='true'></g>
</svg>
```

Can't make it work with tabindex or focusable tho.

**Edit I - 11/29/2022**

I am logging the active/focused element like this

```
@HostListener('document:keydown.tab', ['$event'])
  omitFocusedElement(e: KeyboardEvent) {
    console.log(document.activeElement)    
  }
```

Tabbing order breaks and the element before the nested svg keeps the focus, tabbing does not go any further then

So instead, I tried something else

```
<parent-component>
  <input>
  <svg>
    <g (click)='doSomething' tabindex='0'></g>
  </svg>
  <input>
</parent-component>
```

This way the svg element becomes focusable.

But I need to make it work, when a svg is wrapped by a component.

**Edit II - 11/30/2022**

So appearantly the reason that those elements could not receive focus was, that the component which contains the svg was set to ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom. Because when i removed that, svg elements become focusable.

The downside to this is, that i need to use this encapsulation.

Comment: g is not a rendered element it's just a container. Use tabindex with a rect for instance and it should work.

Comment: here it says, that tabindex can be used with g element https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g#:~:text=The%20SVG%20element%20is,with%20the%20element.

Comment: sure, but it doesn't really do anything because <g> isn't rendered.

Comment: @RobertLongson appearantly the g renders a <path> child element which inherited the tabindex attribute from the <g> element. but the <path> element is still not focusable